# Primefaces menuButton not working after version update 6.2 -> 7.0

Tags: java, user-interface, primefaces

As the title says, after a version update on primefaces (6.2 to 7.0), menuButtons stopped working. When clicked, any menuButton dont show the submenu that it should. No errors are raised, it just doesn't works. Using:

netbeans 8.2

java SE 8 (JDK 8u211)

primefaces 7.0

Anyone has some idea of the reason why is not working?

**Update**:

xhtml code:

[image]

bean code:

[image]

console:

[image]

Comment: have you checked the JavaScript Console for errors?  Can you please paste your menuButton code that is not working.